# gcc makefile won't compile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

My final executable (this is in unix though) will be proj07.

```
proj07: /user/cse320/Projects/project07.driver.o proj07.support.o
    gcc -Wall /user/cse320/Projects/project07.driver.o proj07.support.o

proj07.support.o: proj07.support.c
    gcc -c  proj07.support.c
```

This creates proj07.support.o but no proj07 exists after compilation. I don't get an error so my mistake must be simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's the output:

```
 gcc -c  proj07.support.c
 gcc -Wall /user/cse320/Projects/project07.driver.o proj07.support.o
```

Also I am to use a static driver to test my file which is why the path is like that

Comment: By default, the output of a compilation is named a.out. You have to add a -o flag to gcc to change this. See the manpage for gcc (man gcc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably do have an `a.out` executable. Add `-o $@` to your first `gcc` occurrence and you should be fine.

Comment: Worked! Thanks! Is that just adding a shorthand flag to gcc? And yes I did have an a.out but I didn't think to check it because I compiled something else in the directory that I'm in, so for all I knew it had not changed. Good to know though

Comment: Nope `$@` is a shorthand in `makefile`s to represent the target of the rule.